# Java 8 Method reference to instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Why does the following not work?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MethodRefTest {
   public String passMeAround( String input ) {
      return input + " been passed to me";
   }

   public Function<String, String> testReferences() {
      final Function<String, String> f1 = MethodRefTest::passMeAround;
      return f1;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      new MethodRefTest()
            .testReferences()
            .apply( "foo" );
   }
}
```

Javac tells me:

```
MethodRefTest.java:14: error: invalid method reference
      final Function<String, String> f1 = MethodRefTest::passMeAround;
                                          ^
  non-static method passMeAround(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
1 error
```

I don't understand **why the context is static**. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168806/java-8-method-reference-to-non-static-method) but it does not seem to answer the problem at hand.

## EDIT

Also according to [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), "Reference to an *instance method* of an arbitrary object of a particular type" are possible via `ContainingType::methodName`

## EDIT 2

@marko-topolnik helped me understand my mistake here.
`Function<String, String> f1 = MethodRefTest::passMeAround;`
refers to a static method `String MethodRefTest.passMeAround(String)`

```
BiFunction<MethodRefTest, String, String> f1 = MethodRefTest::passMeAround;
```

on the other hand, refers to the instance method of `any instance`, that is passed in the apply clause.

```
BiFunction<MethodRefTest, String, String> f2 = MethodRefTest::passMeAround;
//call instance method
f2.apply(new MethodRefTest(), "some string");
```

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz time to learn Java 8. It's out for quite some time now.

Comment: But @BrianGoetz, `class::method` can (and _does_ in OP's case) resolve to an instance method reference. The error message is misleading because the real problem is the mismatch between the target type and the type of the instance method reference.

Comment: @dabai Regarding your Edit 2, it's a very good explanation for why the compiler may have come up with its error message. It first fixed the type of the method reference, then went to look for such a method. In another example the message may have hit the spot, but in your case it happened to mislead you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you referred to it as

```
MethodRefTest::passMeAround
```

You should have referred to it as

```
this::passMeAround
```

providing the instance to use for context.

A different way to view your current code is to say that `MethodRefTest::passMeAround` is a `BiFunction<MethodRefTest, String, String>` and this lambda shape does not match the target site. So, alternatively, you may have written

```
public BiFunction<MethodRefTest, String, String> testReferences() {
  return MethodRefTest::passMeAround;
}
```

and in the main method

```
final MethodRefTest t = new MethodRefTest();
t.testReferences().apply( t, "foo" );
```

---

The material you have been reading may not be instructive enough, so let me expand. With

```
this::passMeAround
```

you get a lambda object which has *captured* the `this` instance from the context where it was created, but with

```
MethodRefTest::passMeAround
```

you get a "pure", non-capturing lambda which represents the invocation of the specified method on *some* instance, with *some* string argument, so when you `apply` it, you need to pass in both.

Comment: I was following this https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/java-8-method-references-explained-5-minutes/ example.

Comment: Some more explanation is in the "Method References" section of http://www.studytrails.com/java/java8/Java8_Lambdas_FunctionalProgramming.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Change `passMeAround` to static:

```
 public static String passMeAround( String input ) {
      return input + " been passed to me";
   }
```

or refer to it as to instance method:

```
 public Function<String, String> testReferences() {
      final Function<String, String> f1 = this::passMeAround;
      return f1;
 }
```

Comment: "Change passMeAround to static" doesn't solve nor explain anything Why `MethodRefTest::passMeAround` doesn't work? (notice that according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html `ContainingType::methodName` is "Reference to an *instance method* of an arbitrary object of a particular type")

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question about why the context is static, it's because the part before the `::` was the name of a *class* rather than the name of an *instance*.  If you don't have an instance, only static members are accessible.

Comment: But `MethodRefTest::passMeAround` is a legal method reference even though it refers to an instance method. It's just not appropriate at the place where OP used it. Method reference is not a member access expression.