# Intellij - can be replaced with method reference

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Always when I use lambda expressions like this:

```
.map(obj -> foo.makeSomething(obj))
```

IntelliJ suggests: "Can be replaced with method reference...". And when I try then:

```
.map(Foo::makeSomething)
```

I get the following statement: "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Why Idea suggests me I should use method reference if it's not correct?

Comment: Does it actually suggest that replacement? Or is that just what you are writing yourself? I would have expected `foo::makeSomething`, which would work.

Comment: It's `foo::makeSomething`. You want to call the method on the object foo, not on the class Foo. You could also just let IntelliJ transform the code for you (Alt-Enter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Method Reference to non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168806/java-8-method-reference-to-non-static-method)

Comment: which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet TY for that shortcut - jeez for the life of me I couldnt figure out how to tell IJ to do it! All it gave was a useless popup even more useless suggestion to go to settings where there was nothing relevant to this exact code !! Leaning more and more towards Eclipse now :( which so nicely has the right-click option

Answer (score 102, accepted):

As you write :

```
map(Foo::makeSomething)
```

the compiler expects one of these two possibilities :

- invoking a `Foo.makeSomething()` instance method on the first parameter of the lambda that has to be so defined as a `Foo`.
- invoking a `Foo.makeSomething()` static method.

The first possibility is eliminated by the compiler as the first parameter of the lambda declared `obj` is not a `Foo`.

And according to your error message, `Foo.makeSomething()` is an instance method :

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

So, the second possibility (invoking a `Foo.makeSomething()` static method) is not legal either as `makeSomething()` is not static.

---

In fact, what you want is applying the `makeSomething()` instance method on a variable that doesn't make part of the lambda parameters.
You can do it but you need to use another syntax.

Instead of specifying `Foo::`, use `foo::`.
In this way, the instance method `makeSomething()` will be applied on the `foo` variable  :

```
map(foo::makeSomething)
```

---

**IntelliJ Intention**

Note that inspection that reports lambdas which can be replaced with method references can also be automatically refactored by the IDE via an intention.
To do that, set the cursor on the lambda (anywhere on it) and display contextual intentions (`Alt+Enter` by default). You should see the intention :

> Replace lambda with method reference

Some screenshots :

[image: intention proposition]

[image: intention result]

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that I can use reference with object. I wa thinking it works only when I call ClassName::metohd.

Comment: You are welcome :) In fact, you have three cases to apply method references: 1)static method, 2)instance method for parameters of the lambda and 3)instance method for a variable not declared in the lambda parameters. And for the last case, the syntax is indeed different.

Comment: As @Eli already said, if the method is in the same Class then you have to use 'this' instead of the Class name.